# How to suppress returning a row in U-SQL IProcessor

Tags: u-sql

I have to suppress returning of a row based on a condition in IProcessor in U-SQL as mentioned in the documentation, A processor operates on a row at a time and produces zero or one row.

I am not able to figure out what to mention in the return statement of IProcessor to achieve this.

Thanks,
Nasir

Answer (score 1):

adding **return null** in IProcessor based on a condition worked.

Comment: Hi Nasir, it would be great if you post a simple, working example of this.  Then it will be really useful to other people landing at this page.

Comment: Hi Bob, I tried doing that it is giving me quite a bit of formatting issues. It is simple example, I will be happy to share, will try again.